# How can I have Miniprofiler just call may log method for the profile messages

Tags: c#, mvc-mini-profiler, miniprofiler

I am building a windows service.

I am trying to have miniprofiler,  intercept ado.net calls and hand the messages to my application's logging system.

All miniprofiler needs to do is to call a static method Log(string text).

I went through the following post and learned how to intercept ado.net calls:

[Using MiniProfiler for direct ADO.net calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28063601/using-miniprofiler-for-direct-ado-net-calls)

It seems that the only unsolved puzzle is to have miniprofile call my log method. How can I do that?

I went through the site  http://miniprofiler.com/, but the documentation is minimal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short: this isn't something MiniProfiler is designed to do, because that's not profiling.

However, you lucked out in how MiniProfiler is implemented here. You can implement [`IDbProfiler`](https://github.com/MiniProfiler/dotnet/blob/d3de9728de6746be91759cc523d5178a37ec9f3c/src/MiniProfiler.Shared/Data/IDbProfiler.cs) yourself that just calls the logger. There are only a handful of methods. [Here's MiniProfiler's implementation](https://github.com/MiniProfiler/dotnet/blob/4e2e094172b58496767a32049c3888f2ea1ec133/src/MiniProfiler.Shared/MiniProfiler.IDbProfiler.cs).

If your implementation just calls your logging method(s), you can re-use all of the ADO.NET bits built for MiniProfiler like this:

```
IDbProfiler logger = new YourLogger();
var conn = new SqlServerConnection(myConnectionString);
var profiledConn = new ProfiledDbConnection(cnn, logger);
// ...do stuff with profiledConn
```